# Past sentence followed by a present

Tags: grammar

> My father was a businessman. Now he is retired.

Is this correct or should I always say:

> My father used to be a businessman and he is retired now.

Comment: Where do people come up with this idea that you can't mix tenses in English? I think there are only two situations where it is a problem. (1) Tenses in dependent clauses work differently in English than in some other languages. (2) People who are writing stories for the first time (even native English speakers) tend to be inconsistent with their tenses and sometimes use two different tenses for things that are happening at the same time, which is confusing.

Comment: It is not only that both are correct, but also they mean different things. The statements "My father was a businessman. Now he is retired." allows the possibility that 'my father' is still a businessman. The statement "My father used to be a businessman and he is retired now." conveys the same information as the previous, with the additional knowledge that 'My father' is (for sure) not a businessman now.

Comment: Sorry, not being a businessman now is not the necessary implication of 'used to'. The 'used to' means that the condition of being a businessman now changed. That change could be that it disappeared, but it can also mean that it just changed somehow without having disappeared entirely. On the other hand 'was a businessman' does allow for the condition to still hold unchanged.

Comment: @Peter Shor. I asked the same question in a comment under a similar post https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/481408/mixed-tenses-present-perfect-future-will#comment1162084_481408. I really would like to know where this misconception comes from. I can't imagine any even half-way decent English teacher promulgating such simplistic nonsense.

Comment: @mama "My father was a businessman. Now he is retired". The past simple puts the being a businessman in the past. If he is retired, he stopped working. So what do you mean that he is still a businessman?

Comment: @anouk: *My father was a bricklayer. Now he's retired - but he still lays just as many bricks every week as he used to, building garden walls and suchlike for friends and family*. Being "retired" can just mean you're not formally "employed", ***and / or*** you no longer depend on the work as your primary source of income, etc. But this is all just splitting hairs.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody told you that you weren't allowed to shift tenses in English, they gave you incorrect information. There are times when you shouldn't shift tenses, but your sentences are perfectly fine.

[Here](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/verb_tenses/verb_tense_consistency.html) is the Purdue Owl discussion on consistency in tenses. Two of their guidelines (which I think apply to most languages with verb tenses):

> General guideline: Do not shift from one tense to another if the time frame for each action or state is the same.
>
> General guideline: Do shift tense to indicate a change in time frame from one action or state to another.

There are cases where tenses in English are treated differently than tenses are in other languages. These cases generally apply to tenses in dependent clauses, and not simple sentences like your example.